# ps inside crontab is not seeing a running process

Tags: python, cron, ps

I have this robot `worker.py`, which I just run as:

```
python worker.py --details
```

There are many problems surrounding this robot, so it keeps going down each 30 minutes.

When the robot is running, `ps aux | grep worker.py` gives me output:

```
root      3870  6.2 11.7 997960 59052 pts/0    Sl   10:47   0:32 python worker.py --details
root      4030  0.0  0.4   9752  2312 pts/0    S+   10:55   0:00 grep --color=auto worker
```

So, I set my cron for running each 10 minutes with this command:

```
cd /path/to/boot && if [ 2 -gt `ps aux | grep worker.py | wc -l` ]; then python worker.py --detail &> /dev/null ; fi
```

The issue is:

- If I just run the command above straight in the command line, it works fine (if the robot is running, nothing happens, if the robot is down, it gets up again).
- When cron runs the command, it creates a new process, every 10 minutes (struggling my database), because it is not seeing the current process, I presume.*

Everything above is made as root, so, I guess it is not about user issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a lock file and check for this lock file. If it is there end the script otherwise start it.

An example command would be [shlock](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/shlock.1.html).

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Shlock  tries to create a lock file named name and write the process ID pid into it.  If the file already exists, shlock will read the  process ID  from  the file and test to see if the process is currently running. If the process exists, then the file will not be created. Shlock exits with a zero status if it was able to create the lock file, or non-zero if the file refers to currently-active process.

Comment: That's an awesome idea, I still don't understant what is going on the entrails, but it does the job, thank you so much  :)

Comment: no problem. ran into that problem a few times myself.

Answer (score 0):

cron is not able to find the process with ps aux, the ps COLUMNS default is 80. i.e. ps command output is truncated to 80 COLUMNS.

```
ps -aef before column set:
admin    28695     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /home/admin/MyP

ps -aef after column set:
admin    28695     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /home/admin/MyPython/test.py
```

Add the columns to the crontab starting like below and it will fix the issue.

crontab with below:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
COLUMNS=160
37 08 * * * /home/admin/MyPython/test.py >>  /home/admin/MyPhon/test.py.log 2>&1 &
```

test.py contains below:

```
cmd1="ps -aef >> /home/admin/MyPython/test_ps.txt; echo COLUMNS: ${COLUMNS} ${Shell}>> /home/admin/MyPython/test_ps.txt;"
print cmd1
os.system(cmd1)
```

Hopefully it answers.